# What happens when we cancel a web request from the browser?

Tags: web-applications, httpwebrequest, httprequest, struts

I'm using a Struts application. I hit a Struts action and then cancel the request in-between (by pressing the ESC key).

My question is "Will that action be executed completely or not"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will that action be executed completely or not?

If the request makes it to the server, then yes, it will be executed completely. The action handler has no way of knowing you aborted the request so it will continue doing it's job.